SQL to LINQ help subtracting data on one table from another table (multiple rows)
I have 2 tables that i'm using to capture a Hours target and Completed hours. one table holds the Original values and the other logs hours. There can be multiple logs. I am trying to create a linq query that adds the logged hours for a specified user and subtracts that number from the main table. for example:
Main table
ID:1 User:User1  Target:20
Log table
ID:1  User:User1  Completed:5
ID:2  User:User1  Completed:8
And the returned value should be
ID:1  User:User1  Target:20  Completed:13  Remaining: 7
here's my linq query
var ah = db.AccumulatedHours.ToList();
var gh = db.GoalHours.Where(m=>m.UserID == 4).ToList();

var rmng = from GH in gh
join AH in ah
on GH.ID equals AH.GH_ID
Select new GoalHours
{
ID = GH.ID,
GoalHours = GH.Target
Completed = AH.Completed
Remaining = GH.Target - AH.Completed
};


"but i cant get it to work in LINQ" - What did you try and what didn't work as expected?

@David, i just updated the question with my linq query

Please add a tag for the data library you use, I guess [entity-framework-core] + a tag for the version [ef-core-xx]. Also, it would help to see the class definitions. Details matter.

If the relationship between GoalHours to AccumulatedHours is one-to-many, you are going to need to group by GoalHours.ID and GoalHours.Target, and then sum the AccumulatedHours.Completedvalues. If there can be zeroAccumulatedHoursrows for a givenGoalHoursrow, you will need the equivalent of aLEFT JOINin your LINQ expression - possibly through the use of a.GroupJoin()`.

What database are you using? (SQL server? MySQL?) What object model? (Entity Framework? EF Core?) What versions of each?

I define two classes below:
    public class AccumulatedHours
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int Completed { get; set; }
    }

    public class GlobalHours
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int Target { get; set; }
    }

Then I used below Linq.
You need to use on GH.UserId equals AH.UserId into userInfos select new for the join:
var ah = new List<AccumulatedHours>
{
    new AccumulatedHours {Id = 1, UserId = 1, Completed = 5},
    new AccumulatedHours {Id = 2, UserId = 1, Completed = 8}
};
var gh = new List<GlobalHours>
{
    new GlobalHours {Id = 1, UserId = 1, Target = 20}
};

var joined = (from GH in gh
    join AH in ah on GH.UserId equals AH.UserId into userInfos
    select new
    {
        userId = GH.UserId,
        target = GH.Target,
        sumOfCompleted = userInfos.Sum(r => r.Completed),
        remaining = GH.Target - userInfos.Sum(r => r.Completed)
    }).ToList();

Results are like this:


First, you should not access database table data and perform a .ToList() before applying all of your joins, filters, and selectors. Doing so will unnecessarily load data (possibly all rows and all columns) into an in-memory collection. Following that, any queries applied to those lists will have no access to the original keys and indexes and will perform the in-memory equivalent of a table scan.
Based on your statement "There can be multiple logs" and the ID columns referenced in your join, it is apparent that the relationship between GoalHours to AccumulatedHours is one-to-many. To get your desired results, your query is going to need to group by GoalHours.ID and GoalHours.Target, and then sum the AccumulatedHours.Completed values.
If there is a possibility of having GoalHours with no matching AccumulatedHours rows (as may be normal for no hours yet recorded), you will need to perform a LEFT JOIN between these tables, or the LINQ equivalent. You will also need to handle the null-sum condition with the SQL ISNULL() or COALESCE() function or the equivalent C# null-coalescing operator ??.
Assuming that a left join is needed, I believe you can achieve your desired results with something like the following SQL
DECLARE @UserID INT = 4

SELECT
    gh.ID,
    gh.Target AS GoalHours,
    ISNULL(SUM(ah.Completed), 0) AS Completed,
    gh.Target - ISNULL(SUM(ah.Completed), 0) AS Remaining
FROM GoalHours gh
LEFT JOIN AccumulatedHours ah
    ON gh.ID = ah.GH_ID
WHERE gh.UserID = @UserID
GROUP BY gh.ID, gh.Target;

Left joins are tricky in LINQ. One approach is to perform a "group join" using the join ... on ... into ... syntax, which will pair up rows from the left side of the join with a (possibly empty) collection of rows from the right side of the join.  This conveniently achieves both the left join along with the equivalent of a group-by. It is then a matter of selecting, summing, and null-coalescing the results.
The LINQ query equivalent would then be something like:
int userID = 4

var query =
    from gh in dbContext.GoalHours
    where gh.UserID == userID
    join ah in dbContext.AccumulatedHours
        on gh.ID equals ah.GH_ID
        into ahGroup
    select new
    {
        ID = gh.ID,
        GoalHours = gh.Target,
        Completed = ahGroup.Sum(ah => (decimal?)ah.Completed) ?? 0,
        Remaining = gh.Target - (ahGroup.Sum(ah => (decimal?)ah.Completed) ?? 0)
    };

As pointed out in comments below, at least some framework versions do not support the GroupJpoin approach. The following is an alternative LINQ representation of a left join that uses the .DefaultIfEmpty() technique. (The null handling logic might need some tweaks though.)
var query2 = 
    from gh in dbContext.GoalHours
    where gh.UserID == userID
    join ah in dbContext.AccumulatedHours
        on gh.ID equals ah.GH_ID
        into ahGroup
    from ahd in ahGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group  new { gh, ahd } by new { gh.ID, gh.Target } into grouped
    select new
    {
        ID = grouped.Key.ID,
        GoalHours = grouped.Key.Target,
        Completed = grouped.Sum(g => (decimal?)g.ahd?.Completed) ?? 0,
        Remaining = grouped.Key.Target - (grouped.Sum(g => (decimal?)g.ahd?.Completed) ?? 0)
    };

The (decimal?) cast operator is needed to properly handle sums for empty lists. The SQL server SUM() function will yield null for an empty list (or a list containing no non-null values). Using this cast together with ?? 0 ensures that the sum for an empty list will return zero. You should the appropriate C# type that matches your Completed column type.
(The above is untested. If I have made an error I welcome comments or corrections.)

In csharp it is where gh.UserID == userID

If you want GROUP BY, use LINQ group by, you query is ineffective.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv - Are your familiar with the .GroupJoin() function and the equivalent join ... into syntax? This operates differently than a regular join. This .NET fiddle produces the correct results for LINQ-to-objects, though I admit I have not tested it with LINQ-to-SQL. See also this SO answer.

I know all  LINQ operators and how they are translated to the SQL. GroupJoin has no equivalent in the SQL world. Your query will produce two subqueries, which is not equivalent for grouping.

Digging into the various articles, it appears that GroupJoin() is supported in EF 6 and 7, but was not initially supported by EF Core. Another note stated that a later version implemented GroupJoin(), but as an OUTER APPLY instead of a true LEFT JOIN. It seems that the answer is object-model dependent. I'll update the answer with an alternate version which uses a .DefaultIfEmpty(), which appears to have wider support.

Assuming you have some DB context defined in your application, you can use:
context.GoalHours
    .Join(
        context.AccumulatedHours, 
        x => x.ID, 
        x => x.GH_ID, 
        (x, y) => new { x.ID, x.Target, y.Completed, Remaining = x.Target - y.Completed })
    .ToArray(); // or .ToArrayAsync()

